# How to properly hide an Admob Banner Ad

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I have a banner ad in my trivia game like so:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

And I want to only show it every 5 questions. What is the proper way to hide the ad? If I simply set adView.setVisibility(View.GONE), is this correct? The reason I ask is because I'm not sure if ads will continue to load/give credit when the AdView is not visible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically you won't get credit for having it as hidden. They will still load, but it was answered in one of Googles Q+As that you will not be getting credit for ads not seen by the end user.

Obviously from a financial point of view that makes sense. In your case, what you are doing is correct, but you won't get credit on the 4 questions in between in which the ad is hidden.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I've searched and haven't seen anyone explicitly point out that there is a need for anything else, so I'm sure you are correct, just want to be sure.

Comment: I'll have a look around - i *think* it's in the docs for the AdView, but i don't remember exactly. You can probably test it yourself by seeing if it counts as a view in your account though.